# Are there sync frameworks or algorithms in java like Microsoft sync framework

Tags: java, cloud, microsoft-sync-framework

Are there sync frameworks or algorithms in java. How typically a syncing is done. I am developing a custom app in java, where I need to support syncing data over the cloud from multiple sources. Microsoft sync framework is very comprehensive framework and developed for .net world. I am ok with some subset of features.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct equivilent.

If you want messaging, you could go for a store and forward approach. You can run [ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/) embedded in app an, and when a message is sent it is held locally until there is connectivity to the main brokers, and then it is delivered.

You can also use [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) to store data in maps that are automatically replicated to other nodes in a cluser.